# javascript getAttribute() doesn't work on iPad2 Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ipad-2, touch-event, getattribute

I'm trying to do a touchBased HTML application, and was testing it on iPad 2. However, there seems to be some issue with the custom attributes in HTML.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('mouseup',onTouchReleased, true);
document.addEventListener('touchend',onTouchReleased, true);

function onTouchReleased(e) {
// Capture the event
if(e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
if(e.stopPropagation)
    e.stopPropagation();
console.log(e.target);
console.log(e.target.getAttribute("itemindex"));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img itemindex="0" src="video.jpg"/>
<div itemindex="1">HELLO1</div>
<p itemindex="2">HELLO2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run it on Chrome/Safari on my PC, i'm able to see the correct `itemindex` in the console when i click on the item.

However, on iPad2, i get the `itemindex` of `<img>` as `0`, which is correct, but in case `div` or `p` the itemIndex is returned as an Error.

**TypeError: Result of expression 'e.target.getAttribute'[undefined] is not a function**

Can someone explain this please, and also enlighten me on any workaround available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `touchend` instead of `mouseup` event for touch devices.

Touch based devices didn't support many mouse events such as `mouseup`, `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseover`, `mouseout` but supports `click` event. You can try your code with `click` event too.

**Update**

If you need to attach event to the `document` you can use following snippet using [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) function

For example:

```
function onTouchReleased(e) {
    // Capture the event
    if(e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    if(e.stopPropagation)
        e.stopPropagation();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var pointTarget = document.elementFromPoint( touch.pageX, touch.pageY );
    console.log(pointTarget);
    console.log(pointTarget.getAttribute("itemindex"));
}
```

Comment: i did that ;-) sorry i forgot to put that in the first edit, now i've added the line.

Comment: Did you try to attach event's to specific elements, not document?

Comment: i did now.`document.getElementById("divElement").addEventListener('mouseup',onTouchReleased, true);
document.getElementById("divElement").addEventListener('touchend',onTouchReleased, true);
` and `<div id="divElement" itemindex="1">HELLO1</div>` but it is still the same

Comment: and what `console.log(e.target)` returns?

Comment: it returns [object HTMLElement]. However, if i change the above code to `document.getElementById("divElement").addEventListener('click',onTouchReleased, true);` instead of `touchend`, it seems to work fine.

Comment: it doesn't actually. The original implementation has got many text elements and is a very dynamic environment. so attaching the event to each element is impossible. also, `click` is not a solution, because i plan to implement swipe action also. but your approach is immensely helpful and it'll help me to explore other ways(if any other way exists)